# Simple flexbox example renders incorrectly in Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

Consider this simple example of `display: flex`:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">A</div>
  <div class="inner">B</div>
</div>

.outer {
  display: flex;
}
.inner {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-basis: 0px;
}
```

Most browsers I have tested render this as `AB`, but Internet Explorer 11 instead renders an `A` and `B` superimposed on each other.

Is this a bug in IE11? If so, is there a way to tweak the CSS to get IE11 to render correctly?

https://jsfiddle.net/oh6x73ca/

Comment: What is the computed value of `flex-shrink` in IE11?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu - `1`, but nothing changes if I add `.inner { flex-shrink: 0; }`.

Comment: The elements should not be allocated any space from the parent's length and therefore the next element should start at the same point as the previous one. I believe IE is the one that renders correctly here. I'm not an expert in flexbox, but so far it looks like you're asking the wrong question :). Changing `flex-basis` to `auto` should fix your "problem" in IE, though.

Answer (score 0):

I added this `.inner {flex-basis: calc(100% - 0px;)}` Css and tested and worked fine.

[image: internet explorer 11]